# How to get access to relationship in model User Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have default `User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasRoleContract
{
    use Notifiable, HasRole;

}
```

With one relationship inside:

```
public function distributor() {

    return $this->hasOne('App\DistributorContacts', 'distributor_id', 'id');
}
```

So, when user passed authorization I can not see this relation in object:

```
{{dd(Auth::user())}}
```

[image]

Comment: {{dd(Auth::user()->distributor)}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use ->with('distributor') on your user Object to get relationships loaded.

e.g.

```
$user = new User()->with('distributor');
dd($user->distributor);
```

or

`Auth::user()->with('distributor');`

Comment: or directly access using Auth::user()->distributor

Comment: Are you sure about `->with('distributor')`? is it lazy loading?

Comment: It return me `Builder` instead one row

Comment: to get records you will use ->first() or ->get() obviously

Comment: If I do `get()` it return all rows, not only related, and `first()` correcponding

Comment: by get() you mean get all matching records and first() only get the first matching record. it's equivalent to LIMIT 1 in MySQL query